# Middle school introductory Newtonian mechanics textbooks?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Are there middle school introductory textbooks on Newtonian mechanics tailored to students taking pre-algebra or algebra concurrently?

Specifically:

- Newtonian mechanics: inertia, momentum, forces, Newton's 3 Laws of Motion (preferably in that order)
- Rigorous mathematically, with many practice problems
- Prerequesites: pre-algebra with perhaps algebra being taken concurrently

<sup>question stubs courtesy "[Are resource recommendations allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698/10024)"</sup>

Comment: I highly doubt such a reference can exist for middle schoolers. Mathematical rigour in Newtonian Mechanics is unachievable without calculus and teaching that to students who haven't even touched upon precalculus is too tall an order.

Comment: @SongofPhysics ∄ non-mathematical, conceptual physics textbooks for middle-schoolers?

Comment: in your question you require textbooks *with* mathematical *rigour*. Non-mathematical and conceptual texts do exist.

Comment: @SongofPhysics Middle-schoolers can at least plug-and-chug, can't they?

Comment: yes, but that doesn't make the content any more rigorous mathematically.

Comment: @SongofPhysics True.

Answer (score -2):

To learn Newtonian mechanics, first of all you must develop some mathmatical skills. I taught myself calculas in 6th grade to accomplish the needs in Physics. So the following are the skills and topics you must be familiar with:

1. Precalculus: This includes trig, algebra,etc. I highly recommend the sl Loney book for trig.
2. Calculus: It is the must. Even Newton himself invented it before discovering his laws. You can read the book by James Stewart.